# Reading specific range of lines in html in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

May I check with you, is there any function in beautifulsoup that can allow me to read a specific range of line from the HTML code and print it?

Comment: Sorry but this logic is fallacious. HTML doesn't bother about *lines*, you can have HTML tags scattered on multiple lines. So parsing HTML lines is broken by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, why? BeautifulSoup is a parser. It parses your HTML that you already have in a variable. When you have it in a variable, say `html`, selecting a range of lines is trivial:

```
print(html.splitlines()[startline:endline])
```

and does not require parsing anything.